# Bitrix24 - выборка последующих задач

Tags: python, битрикс, task, битрикс24

Прошу помощи у знающих коллег. Мне нужно вытащить задачи из **Битрикса**, которые имеют последователей. Использую Python, однако метод **tasks.task.list** возращает задачи без полей, в которых указаны предыдущие задачи. Однако в таблице на сайте с документацией такое поле есть (DEPENDS_ON). Подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Поле `DEPENDS_ON` доступно в фильтре, то есть, чтобы получить задачи, у которых есть предыдущие просто нужно в фильтре указать `>` или `!` нулю.

Еще можно посмотреть список возможных возвращаемых полей в `tasks.task.getFields`

p.s. есть сомнения, что правильно понял проблему, но из вводных проблемы, мы получим задачи, у которых есть предыдущие

Comment: Попробовал - или все задачи возвращает, или ни одной. 
Сделал две тестовых задачи, `id=14` в диаграмме Ганта ссылается на `id=16`.
Фильтры `"DEPENDS_ON": 14`, `...: 16`, `...: '14'`, `...: '16'`, `">DEPENDS_ON": 10`, ..., возвращают пустой список. Использовал fast-bitrix24, python API поверх REST API. У вас под чем этот API заработал, если не тайна? )))

Comment: @dmitry_romanov я не на питоне) есть js обертка и дока к ней https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/tasks/tasks_task_list.php вот и предложил такой вариант

Comment: Я даже руками делал вызов API через https://reqbin.com/ (вызов вебхука), конкретно это поле фильтра не работает как фильтр (всегда даёт `все записи` или `ничего`). Увы.